# Fastest way in Windows 11 to open the "Add Manually" link to add a printer

Tags: printer, windows-11

I'm on a campus with around 40 published printers. We populate default printers for our staff, but if they want to print to an unusual place we'd like them to be able to pick the printer on their own.

In Windows 10, they could still use the old Control Panel option to add printers. This was good, because a combination of factors makes the new Add Printer settings option really awkward to use here, and in fact the printers discovered for the list are often *wrong* for what we want our users to do.

In Windows 11, this option is gone. To get to "Add Manually" you have to go through settings, wait as a list of printers loads, and then finally scroll down past (in our case) as many as 40 printers on our campus before finally getting to this link. I'm especially frustrated that is does not show right away, so you have to just sit there and wait before you can scroll.

Is there a faster way to open the manual Add Printer feature?

Comment: Using PowerShell might be the fastest option: https://4sysops.com/archives/install-remove-list-and-set-default-printer-with-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shortcut to the old ***Add a device*** wizard that has an option right there to **The printer that I want isn't listed** which opens the ***Add printer*** dialog (which is the same as the *Add Manually* one.)

It's not direct to the ***Add printer***/*Add Manually* dialog, but it's the same way it used to be in the old versions of Windows.

1. Create a shortcut file on Windows and for the location enter `rundll32.exe SHELL32.DLL,SHHelpShortcuts_RunDLL AddPrinter`
2. Name the shortcut something recognizable, like ***Add Printers (legacy)***
3. Save the shortcut to a good location of your choice (you can pin it in the Start) for the staff to be able to easily find it (and it should also come up in the Windows Search when looking for *Add Printer*)

[image]